# A for loop to browse (without an index variable) the elements of a cell array in GNU Octave / Matlab

Tags: arrays, indexing, octave, cell-array

Given a cell array, say `c = {'first', 'second', 'third'}`, how can it be browsed in a `for` loop without using an index?

This can be done for arrays, so for `c = [1, 2, 3]`, this would work:

```
for k = c
  ...         # use k here as an element of c
endfor
```

What is the equivalent, elegant way, for a cell array? (Please, note that a cell array is not always transformable into an array.)

Update: It actually works fine as it is (i.e., when `c` is a cell array), but only if the values are stored in a row; it won't work when stored in a column, like `c = {'first'; 'second'; 'third'}`.

Comment: You can loop over a cell array. If you do that, each iterations gets you a column of the cell array. If your cell array is a row vector, then each iteration gets a 1 element cell array.

Comment: @carandraug Thanks for the clarification. That was what I was seeing, but I wasn't sure that was the defined behavior.

Comment: @beaker the defined behaviour of a for loop is to loop over the columns of input. This is not unique to cell arrays, it's the same even for numeric arrays. For example `for x = (1:5)', disp (size (x)); endfor` will iterate only once, with x as the whole `1:5` column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a couple of options:

If the individual elements of `c` are transformable to an array, you can use the indices as the loop variable:

```
for k = 1:numel(c)
   disp(c{k}); 
end

first
second
third
```

This option is closest to what [`cellfun`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Function-Application.html#XREFcellfun) would do. (`cellfun` would be another option to replace the `for` loop entirely.)

If the elements are not transformable to an array (or you just want to do it a different way) you can use `c` as the loop index and grab the contents inside the loop:

```
for k = c
   disp(k{});
end

first
second
third
```

This is the most direct translation of what you do in your example.

Comment: I'm afraid there's a mistake in your second approach, the loop is iterating only once, despite the length of the cell array. Try this: `t = 0; for k = c; disp(k{}); ++t, end`

Comment: @nightcod3r Actually, I get 3 iterations and the final value of `t` is 3. I use `c` exactly as you have it in your question, I'm on 3.8.2 in case that makes any difference.

Comment: You're right. I was using  'c = {'first'; 'second'; 'third'}`, what actually makes a big difference. This makes the answer trivial (even included in the statement of the question), but I'll leave it with an update, just as useful information someone might need.

Comment: Ah, yes it does. In fact I got an error on `disp` when I did it that way.